# How to cast object to every number in a sorting of list-view?

Tags: c#, object, casting

I've taken the class to sort the lst view from msdn

I have got the type the column that i click so:

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    int returnVal = new int();
        // Determine whether the type being compared is a date type.
    switch (field_type.Split('(')[0])
    {
        case "int":
        case "float":
        case "tinyiny":
        case "smallint":
        case "bigint":
        case "bit":
        case "mediumint":
        case "double":
        case "decimal":
        case "unsigned":
            returnVal = 0;
        break;

        // case "
        case "date":
        case "datetime":
            // Parse the two objects passed as a parameter as a DateTime.
            System.DateTime firstDate =
            DateTime.Parse(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text);
            System.DateTime secondDate =
            DateTime.Parse(((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
            // Compare the two dates.
            returnVal = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            break;
        default: // Compare the two items as a string.
            returnVal = String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text, ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
            break;
    }
}
```

In case the column clicked is a number float,int,deciam ecc... how can i write one function that return the max between the 2 object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the available CompareTo methods for the given type. E.g:

```
case "int":
    returnValue = ((int) x).CompareTo((int) y);
```

Comment: I Fixed :    string x1 = ((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text;
string y1 = ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text; returnVal = (Convert.ToInt32(x1)).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(y1));

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    var a = x as IComparable ;
    if (a == null) throw new Exception();
    return a.CompareTo(y);
}
```

Comment: If the field type is int(11) for example i get an exception, why?

Comment: Within x i've got {Text = "something"} but if I digit x. there are only equals, gethashcode, gettype and to string(); .